# Win8 (WINRT) C# not allowing Generic Reflection using MakeGenericMethod

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-runtime

Using Windows 2012 C# for Windows 8 (WinRT/Metro) I am having problems with the following:

```
public class HelperClass
{
    public static bool test()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public static bool test1<T>()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public void runTestMethod()
    {
        Type[] tt = new Type[]{};
        object[] param1 = new object[] {};
        MethodInfo method = typeof(HelperClass).GetRuntimeMethod("test", tt);
        //This works just fine
        object o = method.Invoke(null,param1)
    }
    public void runTestMethod1(PropertyInfo p)
    {
        Type[] tt = new Type[]{};
        object[] param1 = new object[] {};
        MethodInfo method = typeof(HelperClass).GetRuntimeMethod("test", tt);
        MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(p.GetType());
        //This breaks with the error below
        object o = generic.Invoke(null,param1)
    }
}
```

`The API 'D20OGL.BusinessObjects.HelperClass.test[RuntimePropertyInfo]()' cannot be used on the current platform. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248273 for more information.`

The code i'm writing heavily relies on reflection and generics. Anyone know a workaround to this???

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly meant

```
method.MakeGenericMethod(p.PropertyType);
```

or possibly

```
method.MakeGenericMethod(p.DeclaringType);
```

and not

```
method.MakeGenericMethod(p.GetType());
```

Comment: you are 100% right. p.PropertyType was my problem. using p.GetType was a System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo. Thanks for the fix :)